# HtmlElement setAttribute access denied

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, async-await, task

I have a class called Input.cs, where I'm passing the existing form instance in the constructor.

Then there is this code:

```
private async Task PopulateInput(HtmlElement file, string value)
{
    file.Focus();
    var populateTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        file.SetAttribute("value", value); // <- ACCESS DENIED ERROR
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    await populateTask;

    await Task.Delay(500);
}

public async Task Populate(string fieldSelector, string fieldIdentificator, string value, string fieldType = "input")
{
    var elements = mainForm.webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName(fieldType);
    foreach (HtmlElement file in elements)
    {
        if (file.GetAttribute(fieldSelector) == fieldIdentificator) // Example file(input?) name == title
        {
            file.Focus();
            if (fieldType == "input")
            {
                await PopulateInput(file, value);
            }
            else if (fieldType == "upload")
            {
                await PopulateUploadFile(file, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This line: `file.SetAttribute("value", value);` produces an ACCESS DENIED error and I don't have an idea what's wrong with the code.

Exact error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Calling the method:

```
input.Populate(fieldType, fieldIdentificator, value).ContinueWith((_) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Field populated!");
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I've updated the question with the exact error that I'm getting.

Comment: Where are you calling `PopulateInput` from? are you sure `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` is returning the synchronization context you're actually expecting?

Comment: Updated the question again with the calling method. I'm calling it from another class(mainForm).

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith`? Why not simply `await Task.Delay(500)` and then set the file `file.SetAttribute("value", value);`

Comment: It doesn't fill the field and returns the same error. Plus I've made a mistake in my previous comment. I'm calling Populate from another class and Populate calls PopulateInput, but this can be seen in the code too. Thanks for taking time to help me!

Comment: The problem is you're calling `PopulateInput` from a thread other than the UI thread. That is why you cant access any UI elements inside it. Can you assign `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` to a local variable and actually see which context it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64721/discussion-between-user1410644-and-yuval-itzchakov).